# JSON Decode not working for loop

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use json_decode within a loop function, basically I am trying to create a standard set of documents for a client based on certain choices they make.

The earlier code isnt really important but does work, so far it inserts relevant records from a master table to a client table, however one of the fields within this table is a json array and is used to store document (uploaded) information.

I need to figure out why the code below doesnt work.  The query does, and later on (which I havent copied) there is an insert query, which does work but I do need to deconstruct the json field, change some of the field values and then re-encode in which will be the value in new table.

There is no error code, but the values associated with the json decode element, ie name1, usrname1, size1 and type1, return as null values.

I have used both these types of functions before without issue but have never combined them in a foreach style approach so not too sure if I have missed something.

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong with the json_decode part, many thanks.

```
//Add Template Documentation
//step 1 identify which documentation set is required
$sql = "SELECT * FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql); 
$results = $rs;
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{


//Step 3 Decode Attachment Field
$attachmentArr = json_decode($row["attachment"],true);

//values from Attachment Array
$name1 = $attachmentArr["name"];
$usrName1 = $attachmentArr["usrName"];
$size1 = $attachmentArr["size"];
$type1 = $attachmentArr["type"];
$searchStr1 = $attachmentArr["searchStr"];
```

Comment: Pretty hard to help you if you don't show us what the JSON you're getting from `$row["attachment"]` looks like.

Comment: What is in the `$row['attachment']` variable? Try to debug it or just simply use `var_dump()`

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row)` and see what comes out. And post the JSON that is producing the `NULL` values

Comment: Sorry this is what the $row["attachment"] looks like `[
   {
    "name":"ClientFiles\/POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement,Rev0_wg1t36oh.pdf",
    "usrName":"POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement,Rev0.pdf",
    "size":172223,
    "type":"application\/pdf",
    "searchStr":"POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement, Rev0.pdf,!:sStrEnd"
   }
]`

Comment: I have done a var_dump and this is result array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(37) "Templates/_20140917_1226_j7puhawb.csv" ["usrName"]=> string(18) "_20140917_1226.csv" ["size"]=> int(221) ["type"]=> string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel" ["searchStr"]=> string(28) "_20140917_1226.csv,!:sStrEnd" } }